# Print a numerical hollow square pattern using recursive functions in c++

Tags: c++, recursion

I've been trying to print a square numerical pattern like this one:

```
    12345
    2   4
    3   3
    4   2
    54321
```

But I can't seem to find the correct way to code a recursive function to do it.
I've only managed to print a numerical triangle, but the square has been killing me.

```
#include <iostream> 
using namespace std; 
void print_row(int no, int val) 
{ 
    if (no == 0) 
        return; 
    cout << val << " "; 
 
    print_row(no - 1, val); 
} 
 
void pattern(int n, int num) 
{ 
    if (n == 0) 
        return; 
    print_row(num - n + 1, num - n + 1); 
    cout << endl; 
  
 
    pattern(n - 1, num); 
} 
int main() 
{ 
    int n = 5; 
    pattern(n, n); 
}
```

output:

```
1
2 2
3 3 3
4 4 4 4
5 5 5 5 5
```

Code to output a square shape pattern using recursion.This is as far as I've gotten to try and print a numerical square, I don't know how to print it out with ascending and descending numbers.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
using namespace std;

void line( int row, int num )
{
   if ( row < 0 ) return;
   char c = row * ( num - row - 1 ) ? ' ' : '*';
   cout << '*' << string( num - 2, c ) << "*\n";
   line( row - 1, num );
}

int main()
{
   int n;
   cout << "Input side (n > 2): ";   cin >> n;
   line( n - 1, n );
return 0;
}
output:
*****
*   *
*   *
*   *
*****
```

Comment: Please show the output the program actually generates.

Comment: I already edited it in  @cigien

Comment: Ok, but what about the program for the square? How far have you gotten with that?

Comment: There it is. @cigien

Comment: you can add another  parameter direction to the recursive function parameter, and control the order using the direction like 1 for right 2 for left etc...

Answer (score 1):

This is one of the ways to solve this question.

The `pattern` function prints the hollow square pattern while the `printSubRows` is responsible for generating the middle portion.

```cpp
void printSubRows(int n,int i,int c) {
  if (c==n-2) return;
  //adjust the space according to your requirements
   cout << i << "   " << n-i+1 << endl;
   printSubRows(n,i+1,c+1);
}
void pattern(int n) {
    //prints the first row
    for (int i=1;i<=n;i++) cout << i;
    cout << endl;
    //recursive function to print the middle part
    printSubRows(n,2,0);
    //prints the last row
    for (int i=n;i>0;i--) cout << i;
    cout << endl;
}
```